# Method converts strings in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to objective-c and I need help with this.

A phone number in this country has 10 digits like 6195946191 or 619JYDN191. It is hard to read a phone number formatted like that. One common format is 619-594-6191. Add the method phoneFormat to the NSString class. The method phoneFormat converts strings like

```
@"6195946191", @"619 594 6191", @"619 5946191" and @"619-594-6191" to @"619-594-6191".
```

That is all the methods below will return @"619-594-6191"

```
[@"6195946191" phoneFormat]
[@"619 594 6191" phoneFormat]
[@"619 5946191" phoneFormat]
[@"619-594-6191" phoneFormat]
```

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: This is not a "write my code for me" site.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two stages. First remove all undesirable characters (everything that is not a digit? depends what input you are expecting). Personally, I would probably use NSScanner for this, though I can think of other ways.

Now you are guaranteed you have 10 digits in succession, so insert a hyphen after the 3rd and 6th characters and you're done.